# Painted eggshell paint on mud/drywall without primer

Tags: drywall, painting, primer

My painter didn’t prime on any of the new drywalls!  No primer before he painted Sherwin Williams egg-shell paint, and no primer before he applied mud. So paint on mud - what we suspect anyway.   I wanted smooth walls. The drywalls are the normal gray and purple ones.
Now we discover that the paint layers can be peeled off once you cut in a bit.(started where he used tape along the trims..)
So How to fix this?!
I Hope we can apply something over without having to peel all off (even though we did peel some walls already). Also a painter said to try oil-based primer over the paint without peeling it off. Would that work?
I still need to do mud work because his is not good. Not smooth and not straight. Help! [image][image]

Comment: Nothing over the existing paint will stop the pealing. usually paint sticks better even soaks in to mud the mud must have been dusty or not wiped off prior to painting.

Comment: Then my next question is how hard should I try to peel it off... it looks finish from the surface unless you cut it a little and with a scraper you can begin to peel layers off. Sometimes it get to peeling a thin layer of the purple paper of the drywall.  What’s good?

Comment: Usually not priming just means you use more coats of paint to get even color. What you have going on is something more than just no primer.

Comment: I would agree that failure to clean the drywall probably has more to do with this than lack of primer. We drywalled, mudded & painted a storage area 2 years ago and are having zero issues with paint peeling, despite not using any primer. I thoroughly vacuumed the walls then wiped with a damp cloth prior to painting.

Answer (score 2):

I would call in a "real" professional dry wall finisher for his input. I had a guy come to my house to install the drywall, tape and finish. His tape joints including the mud were about18" wide. He did the best damn finish job I have ever seen.

Once you get your job corrected have a good painter redo the paint job and ask how he will apply the paint.